# public facebook Messenger Bot

Tags: bots, messenger

I created messenger bot,but i have a problem.only I can test it.when I text him he replies me,but if my friend tries to do same thing,nothing happens.
what is the best way to be messenger bot public?

Comment: Hey, check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to submit your app for review and make it public.
More details: [Launch Messenger Bot](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/product-overview/launch)

Answer (score 0):

You can add their to testers in your fb dev console or make public in "app review " bookmark but you have to check if you did everything things "add profile picture,add private police etc."

Answer (score 0):

To allow other user such as your friend test without having to go to any review process, you can add such users as admin of the app on you app dashboard.

I noticed only users with admin priviledges can do this at the time of writing this.